# How much or many the scores

Tags: grammaticality, countable-nouns

Is this sentence correct? Grammarly does not take it a mistake.

> There you can see how **much** the scores will change.

Comment: Why should it? It's not a mistake.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See also [ell.se]

Comment: It is not incorrect. It is not clearly expressed. Please ask your question on English Language Learners site.

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in the
singular or *“**these** Xes”* in the plural in many common and less
exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners don’t realize
that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this, that, these,
those* which native speakers customarily use for these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your sentence:

> There you can see how much the scores will change.

Yes, **much** is correct here, because we're talking about the rate of change of the scores, and, as stated in the question's title, not about the scores.

Answer (score 1):

"Is the below sentence correct?" <-- below cannot be used as an adjective.

(you want to say: "Is the sentence below correct?")

As for the statement: "There you can see how much the scores will change."

Yes! If you factor out that 'much' implies the 'rate of change (of the scores)' and since change is uncountable, 'much' is expected here.

Personally, I wouldn't use 'will' (considering it is a modal that serves others functions which are probably not relevant in the statement) but instead say, "are likely to"  or "are expected to" or simple "are to" (change).

Answer (score -1):

Further to Alex StJohn's and Alberto Solano's answers:

If we refer to the amount by which a score changes, we would say e.g. "The score will change by 10 points". The word "by" is needed. Therefore, if the OP's sentence refers to the amount of change, it needs the word "by". It should be one of the following:

- There you can see by how much the scores will change.
- There you can see how much the scores will change by.

Comment: Downvoter, please could you explain how you think my answer could be improved? And, just in case you don't know, if you disapprove of an answer a user has posted, it's not the done thing to downvote two more answers which that user posted as well.